# How to create a thread synhronization a method that can be executed by N threads?

Tags: java

I whould like to block a method execution from more thab 3 threads. The method can be executed recursively. I have following agly code. Can I achive this by using better way?

```
private static class MyHolder {
    private static Semaphore limitThreadsSemaphore = new Semaphore(3);
    private static Set<Thread> asquiredThreads = new HashSet<Thread>();
}

@Override
public void someMethod() {
    if (!MyHolder.asquiredThreads.contains(Thread.currentThread())) {
        synchronized (MyHolder.asquiredThreads) {
           if (!MyHolder.asquiredThreads.contains(Thread.currentThread())) {
               try {
                   MyHolder.limitThreadsSemaphore.acquire();
                   MyHolder.asquiredThreads.add(Thread.currentThread());
               } finally {
                   MyHolder.limitThreadsSemaphore.release();
                   MyHolder.asquiredThreads.remove(Thread.currentThread());
               }
           }
        }
    }
    return super.someMethod();
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest approach would be to refactor the recursive method to be private and then have the public method unconditionally acquire the semaphore, call the private method and then release the semaphore again. The recursive calls route straight to the private method so don't go through the semaphore guard code.

If that is not an option then the simplest approach I can think of would be to use a ThreadLocal flag

```
ThreadLocal<Object> alreadyIn = new ThreadLocal<>();
public void someMethod() {
  boolean needSem = (alreadyIn.get() == null);
  if(needSem) {
    semaphore.acquire();
    alreadyIn.set(new Object());
  }
  try {
    // do stuff
  } finally {
    if(needSem) {
      alreadyIn.remove();
      semaphore.release();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @MaratKamalov in what way? The point of ThreadLocal is that it is thread-local - this thread's value of `alreadyIn` can't be affected by any other thread so there's no race condition.

Comment: As long as nothing outside `someMethod` touches `alreadyIn` it should be perfectly safe.

Comment: You added finally block, it fix an issue. It should work. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I guess "someMethod" is the method you want to block execution,yeah?. Why don'y you do this? :

```
private static class MyHolder {
    private static Semaphore limitThreadsSemaphore = new Semaphore(3);

    public boolean semaphoreAdquired = false; //Make it private

    public Semaphore getSemaphore()
    {
        return limitThreadsSemaphore;
    }
}



@Override
public void someMethod() {

    boolean ReleaseSemaphore = false;

    if(!semaphoreAdquired)
    {
        MyHolder.getSemaphore().acquire();
        semaphoreAdquired = true;
        ReleaseSemaphore = true;
    }
    super.someMethod();
    if(ReleaseSemaphore)
    {
        MyHolder.getSemaphore().release();
        semaphoreAdquired = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Because, this method can be executed recursively. In this case I don't need a block.

Comment: Try now the edited code, you don't say you need to make recursive calls.

Comment: Sorry, question was edited. I don't undestand your solution. Method should work in 3 threads concurenly, 4th thread should be blocked. But your solution don't limit threads count. First thread sets semaphoreAdquired to true and works very long. All others threads wouldn't be blocked by this code. Your solution will work if I will use ThreadLocal for semaphoreAdquired.

Comment: The semaphoreAdquired variable is not shared by the threads, is not static. You can put this variable in your threads local variables if you want.

Comment: Local variables is shared by the threads in Java. And you new edited code will not compile.

Comment: Each time you create a thread, you create an object of the Thread class, so the properties/Variables in that thread are not shared with another threads if you don't declare them to be static. Obviously, I don't know for what class you inherit in someMethod, so put the "semaphoreAdquired" variable in a proper place and get it in a proper way

Answer (score 0):

Based on the documentation for [Semaphor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html), this should be achievable using *only* `acquire()` and `release()` around the critical section. Also, you should be able to put the semaphor in the current class, no need for a separate class to contain the Semaphor.

```
private static Semaphore limitThreadsSemaphore = new Semaphore(3);
@Override
public void someMethod() {
     limitThreadsSemaphore.acquire();
      // do work.
     limitThreadsSemaphore.release();
}
```

**Update**: If you need to call a method recursively within a thread, then the easiest way is to use a helper method to acquire the semaphor, and then invoke the recursive method from that helper method after acquiring the sempahor. You would call the helper instead of the original method in all the initial calls.

```
private static Semaphore limitThreadsSemaphore = new Semaphore(3);
public void someMethodHelper() {
     limitThreadsSemaphore.acquire();
     someMethod();
     limitThreadsSemaphore.release();
}
@Override
public void someMethod() {
  // do work, with recursive calls.
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work for recursively invocation. Thread doesn't blocked if used synhronization block, but semaphore acquire 2 times for one thread.

Comment: @user3153317, Please update your question to mention this requirement.

Comment: I can't use anoter method invocation. Only if you use some logic of this invocation in someMethod().

Comment: @user3153317, Just reorder it. Put the semaphors inside `someMethod()` and do the real work inside `helper()`. This way you do not change your API to the outside world, but you are internally satisfyin your requirement.

Comment: I can't do it, because I have a huge logic between this method invoced again recursively. I didn't invoke it from this class.

Comment: @user3153317, You have to decide exactly where your critical sections are. If you are worried about holding a semaphor for too long, your current solution has this problem as well. You will have to clarify what you mean by "huge logic betwee nthis method invoked again recursively" in your question, if you want more specific assistance.